# AJAX database access in PHP. The simplest way

Tags: php, mysql, xml, ajax

I'm looking for the simplest possible solution to get mysql database records as XML output using PHP. That means no third party APIs. Just pure php code and as little of it as possible.

I posted a similar article for c# in my blog and im looking for an equivalent that will work on any hosting company.

Here is the link (i couldn't add  tag from my iphone) 
http://desalasworks.com/ajax-database-access-in-c-sharp-the-simple-way/

Thanks in advance. 
Steven

Comment: Specifically what format do you want the XML file in?

Comment: Specifically why do you want to avoid 3rd party APIs?

Comment: Does it matter? TheAdamG: Javascript can parse any standard XML format so long as its consistent. Malfist: i was after the core solution not digging it out of an API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this for one solution:

http://www.kirupa.com/web/mysql_xml_php.htm

Or to utilise PHP5 specific functionality:

http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/dom.html